# Can't find copyright information in magento

Tags: html, magento

I'm trying to change the footer info 2006-20012 on my footer of magento site, I've searched all the files at location:

public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html

and saw the  “footer.phtml” file still can't find the info. I need help as I have searched almost all folders of my website.

Thanks

Comment: Have you turned on template path hints to find it? It can differ depending on the installation like Mark says

Answer (score 9):

It can be accessed via the admin under System > Configuration > Design > Footer

Comment: Can't find it in any folder or file because, like a lot of stuff in Magento, it lives in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Because it will differ, depending on the theme you're using, you need to turn on template hints.

From the admin panel:
System >> Configuration >> Developer >> Debug

A guide can be found here:  http://www.westwideweb.com/wp/2009/08/04/magento-how-to-turn-on-template-path-hints-and-inline-translation/